# Is it right to say We don't have a chance for tomorrow?

Tags: phrase-usage

If I want to say that the relationship has no future, can I say: We don't have a chance for tomorrow?

Answer (score 1):

*Tomorrow* and *future* have different meanings. If you mean any day after today (the present time), you could say:

> We don't have **any** chance **in the future**.

Using *any* emphasizes that there is *no* future.